# Error catching in my twitter bot

Tags: python, twitter, try-catch

So i wrote a twitter bot and it pulls the top submission from a certain subreddit and posts it to twitter.

It runs as a cron job, if the top post is the same as last time it ran the twitter api throws an error that the post is a duplicate, im looking to catch this error and then re run the function with the key incremented so as to try the next post heres my code (api credentials left out)

```
def pull_reddit_post(key):
    r = reddit.Reddit(user_agent='ghettoTwit')
    submissions = r.get_subreddit('ghettojerk').get_hot(limit=10)
    post = [str(x) for x in submissions]
    post = post[key]
    post = post.lstrip('0123456789: ')
    return post

def tweet_reddit_post(key):
    global api 
    post = pull_reddit_post(key)
    api.PostUpdates(pull_reddit_post(key))

try:
    key = 0
    tweet_reddit_post(key)
except:
    key = key + 1
    continue
else:
    break
```

Comment: What's the point of this line: `post = pull_reddit_post(key)`

Comment: Okay, so what is your question? StackOverflow is generally for specific questions, not asking people to write your code for you.

Comment: What if you lost you internet connection ? That's why the except without argument isn't a sane way to approach error catching.

Comment: im going to clean up the error catching once i get the basic function working, i appreciate the input

Comment: not trying to get my code written for me was just asking what is wrong with my catch.... works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just edit the try...except and put it inside a loop

```
key = 0

while True:
    try:
        tweet_reddit_post(key)
        break
    except:
        key += 1
```